# How to get my custom module to recognized a exported view?

Tags: views, 8, installation

I have created a view and then exported it normally to a yml file. Then I put this yml file into my mycustommodule/config/install folder.

So current its named `mycustommodule.view.user_assigned.yml`

However when I uninstall the module and reinstall it to see if it will upload the view, it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I copied and pasted the yml file itself so there should be no errors there. The only thing I did was remove the UUID string since I read elsewhere it was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of a config item filename is the module responsible for the config type, not the module installing it.

In your case that's "views", so the file should be named *views.view.user_assigned.yml*.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. I have a question though, in my original file naming convention, I put 'view' there for my own sake, to recognize this as a view and not another entity.

When I did your approach, Views.view.(whatever here), it works, but if I put Views.(whatever here), it does not work. It requires Views.view. Where can I find documentation regarding this so I know how to properly name things? Otherwise, I am blind and guessing in the dark.

Comment: You can go to admin > config sync > export > single item. Then under the text area you will see the name of the config file once you’ve made a selection.

Answer (score 0):

This is by concept, uninstalling a module does not remove config listed in `config/install` - and therefore the config also won't also update through reinstalling. (Actually I thought there even would be some error message like *"can't install because config object already exists"*)

But you can add an `enforced` dependency to your config, which will delete the config object when you uninstall the module (and therefore also update it when you reinstall it).

Add this to your `.yml`

```
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - mycustommodule
```

Comment: The file is named incorrectly so the config never gets installed in the first place (hence no duplicate config error message)